# Como eu posso criar um filtro de urls indisponiveis? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, eu queria saber como eu posso filtrar certos subdominios que simulariam a marca da minha empresa por ex: em uma hospedagem gratuita o usuário digita um subdominio para o endereço de seu site.  caso ele digitase um subdominio como apenas a palavra "**blog**" ou "**forum**", "**notícias**". apareceria um aviso informando que esse subdominio e invalido. eu gostaria de um script client-side, e so para evitar que usuarios criem sites simulando a marca da minha empresa como por ex: ele não poderia criar blog.meudominio.xy, filtrar essas palavras, mas quando digitado "blog21.meudominio.xy" não aparecer esse aviso.

[image: **Exemplo**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um array no `js` e utilizar o método `indexOf`. Ex:

```js
const subdomainDisabled = ["blog", "news", "cdn"];
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (subdomainDisabled.indexOf(input.value) >= 0) {
    alert("Choose another subdomain");
    input.value = "";
  } else {
    $('#ID-DO-MODAL').modal("show");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="subdomain" />
<button type="button">Register</button>
```

Comment: muito obrigado era isso mesmo so faltava esse detalhe pra terminar o projeto!, mas novamente eu analisei o codigo, eu utilizo um modal bootstrap para dizer que tudo ocorreu bem poderia me dizer como fazer uma condiçâo? se o dominio for invalido não exiba o modal e exiba o alert de aviso, se tudo ocrrer certo, exiba o modal.

Comment: @HellFiveOsborn, modifiquei minha resposta. Basta substituir `ID-DO-MODAL` pelo `ID` do seu `modal`.